# SoX save output to the input filename

Tags: sox

I have been using commands like `sox input.wav output.wav reverb 50 50 100`. How can I override the input file? In other words, I want to read from let's say `audio.wav` and apply reverb to that and save it as `audio.wav`. I have messed around with different flags from the documentation, but I cannot get any of them to work. When trying the naive `sox audio.wav audio.wav reverb 50 50 100`, I get `Premature EOF on .wav input file`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SoX does not offer the possibility to overwrite the input file.

This has the benefit of always leaving you with a backup afterwards.
If processing of a large audio file would crash halfway through, then you will not be left with a half-finished file. Just discard the output file and try again.

If you see no value in keeping the original file, then just throw it away and rename the new file.

```
sox input.wav output.wav reverb 50 50 100 && mv output.wav input.wav
```

I deliberately used `&&` to separate the two commands, to prevent `mv` being executed in case SoX fails.

If you need this more often, then just turn it into a Bash script or function.